# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API - can't publish on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebAPI and now I want to deploy it to the IIS-Server.

In debug mode, I can make requests via postman and I get the correct results.

But when I deploy the web api to the iis-server, I can't call the web api services. So it some kind doesn't work correctly.

I have followed several guides how to do it, here is one of the guides:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1216729/Get-NET-Core-Web-API-Hosted-in-IIS

It still doesn't work.

ProductController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CodeBaseFx;
using FurnitureContract.Services;
using FurnitureContract.Services.Model;
using FurnitureContract.Services.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FurnitureContract.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Product")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductService service = ServiceFacade.ProductService;

        public ProductController(IProductService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetById")]
        public IEnumerable<Product> GetByProductId(string productId)
        {
            return service.GetByProductId(productId);
        }

        [HttpGet("GetByDesc")]
        public IEnumerable<Product> GetByProductDesc(string productDesc, string language)
        {
            var lng = CoreFacade.Language.GetLanguage(language);
            return service.GetByProductDesc(productDesc, lng);
            //return service.GetByProductDesc(productDesc, LanguageType.it);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FurnitureContract.WebApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

I have also installed the **Microsoft .NET Core Windows Server Hosting Bundle File** on the IIS Server

Here my Deployment steps:

1. I have published my project to a folder and then copied it to the web server on the target folder.
2. I've created an application pool with **no managed code** setting.
3. Then I've created a new application and selected the application pool above and set the physical path to the web api folder.

When I try to make a request via postman, I don't get any result.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem:

1. I have forgot to open the specific ports on the firewall
2. I had a problem on the server, because the application pool that ive configured, had not the right permissions to communicate with the database